# Extract string with regular expression containing repeating/recursive patterns (SWIFT IOS)

Tags: regex, swift

Is there a way to extract the string "`{{  bla  {{ blu  }} blo  }}`" from "`beginbla {{  bla  {{ blu  }} blo  }} endbla.`"
with regular expressions in SWIFT.

TEXT:

```
beginbla {{  bla  {{ blu  }} blo  }} endbla.
```

requered extract:

```
{{  bla  {{ blu  }} blo  }}
```

I realized, that I am not able to extract recursive patterns. In my sample I managed to extract "`{{  bla  {{ blu  }}`", but I need "`{{  bla  {{ blu  }} blo  }}`"

Any hints?

Comment: Do you need recursive behavior or just greedy regex like [`{{.*}}`](https://regex101.com/r/dA3tD3/1)? It depends on whether you are looking for smaller substrings inside larger strings with matching `{{`/`}}` delimiters, or you have individual strings with already balanced delimiters and you need to take the only delimited sequence in those strings.

Comment: I need recursive behaviour. I found that several engines are supporting the (?R) for recursive regex.

Comment: ICU regex used in Swift regex flavor does not support recursion. You'll have to find a workaround, or limit to some specific depth, e.g. to just 2: [`{(?:(?!}}|{{).)*{(?:(?:(?!}}|{{).)*{{(?:(?!}}|{{).)*}})+(?:(?!}}|{{).)*}}`](https://regex101.com/r/dA3tD3/2). But looking at it, you would like to create your own parser.